# Discord py Emoji URL issue

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi I'm currently experiencing some issues with getting the URL directly from an emoji to create an emoji (Example *e :Cat: namehere) it throws up no errors but doesn't do what its supposed to do which is get the url of the emoji and make it into an emoji

side note `Union[discord.Emoji, discord.PartialEmoji]` is what im having an issue with since im trying to get the url directly from the emoji with out this piece it works by doing (*e link name)

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['e'])
async def emoji(ctx, url: Union[discord.Emoji, discord.PartialEmoji], str, *, name):
    async with bot.ses.get(url) as r:
        try:
            if r.status in range (200, 299):
                img = BytesIO(await r.read())
                bytes = img.getvalue()
                emoji = await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(image=bytes, name=name)
                await ctx.send(f"ez pz heres ur emoji {emoji}")
            else:
                await ctx.send("ERROR WHAT DID YOU DO")
        except discord.HTTPException:
            await ctx.send(random.choice(joke))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `url` is a [discord.Emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20emoji#discord.Emoji) and not actually a URL. What you should do is rename the parameter to `emoji`, and then at the top of your function put `url = emoji.url`

If you need the URL as a PNG, you can do `emoji.url_as('png')`

- [discord.Emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20emoji#discord.Emoji)
- [discord.PartialEmoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20partialemoji#discord.PartialEmoji)
- [Emoji.url (or PartialEmoji.url)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20partialemoji#discord.PartialEmoji.url)
- [Emoji.url_as() (or PartialEmoji.url_as())](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20partialemoji#discord.PartialEmoji.url_as)

Comment: This also didn't work and also removes the main part of the cmd which is being able to use links as another source to make emojis

Comment: @ChillinAkaMac it doesn't remove that feauture, because the type is `Union[discord.Emoji, discord.PartialEmoji]` and will never be a url

Comment: Ah yes i see what you mean now sorry i'm a bit new to python i tried out exactly what you said and it still gave the same result of no error but also no emoji. Unsure of what could be the error since it works when i use it to just send the url of emoji:/